# Setting MAINPID from podman container

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

I'd like to send a systemd notification with readiness and main pid. Unfortunately, it seems like systemd doesn't cope with translating pids from different namespaces. (Just a guess...)

Specifically, I'm staring a service with:

```
ExecStart=podman run --rm --cgroups=disabled -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd ... script.sh
```

And the started script does:

```
echo "MAINPID=$$" | nc -uUN -w0 /run/systemd/notify
```

This doesn't seem to change anything. The MAINPID is set to either conman (default) or podman (`--sdnotify=ignore`). Then again, I'm effectively sending `MAINPID=1` from inside the running container.

Is there some workaround here to ensure a specific process inside the service/container becomes the MAINPID instead?

Comment: Maybe this could give you some ideas: I made an experiment with a  systemd system service `User=` 
 and `StartExecPost=+/some/path` (see [GitHub comment](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12778#issuecomment-1586255815)). Note, starting the path with a plus sign instructs systemd to run the command as root. I learned that __systemd__ accepts a sent MAINPID when it is sent from an unexpected process if the process is running as root.

Comment: @ErikSjölund it's disgusting and it works :⁠-⁠) wanna use it in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a path in  [ExecStartPost=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service#ExecStartPre) that starts with a plus sign, instructs **systemd** to run the command as root. I learned that systemd accepts a sent MAINPID when it is sent from an unexpected process if the process is running as root.

If you want to experiment, you could try

```
ExecStartPost=+/some/path
```

**References:**
I made an experiment with a systemd system service [User=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=) and [ExecStartPost=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service#ExecStartPre) (see [GitHub comment](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12778#issuecomment-1586255815)).

Comment: This worked great. You may also need to set `NotifyAccess` to the right value.